# Access to path is denied moving a directory using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

When I tried to cut and paste the directory (subfolder and files) it gives me error access to the path is denied. Sometime it works when I upload any files to that directory then it shows error.

I have full access to that directory and subdirectories.
I am able to delete and upload files under that directory, but cannot move that Directory to any other location.

I have tried:

1. Full Access to network service and Everyone.
2. Update identity of application pool.

I have also tried this

```
 DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
 dSecurity.AddAccessRule(
    new FileSystemAccessRule("everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,AccessControlType.Allow));
dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);

 //move function
 Source = Server. MapPath (source);
  destination = Server.MapPath(destination);  
  If (! Directory. Exists (destination))
   {                           
    Directory.Move(source, destination);                              

   }
   catch (Exception e)
  {
      return e.Message;
  }
```

If you have any idea why I am getting this error please let me know.

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: error is coming from production or localhost?

Comment: did you try impersonating as IIS user http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708(v=WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that one of the files in the "source" directory is in use and cannot be moved. Try moving each file in the directory one by one in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

as @Arsen said try to move each file one by one,,

Also check for

> > **Mode of the directory
> >
> > **Permission of user who try to move the directory
> >
> > **else, probably try to move the directory as a superuser.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that one of the files in the source directory is using by another process and can not moved. Try to moving each file one by one then you get some files is in use by another process.